# Ubuntu 22.04 - Default theme not working

Tags: themes, 22.04

Having some problems with Ubuntu 22 after updating it from 20, I haven't used the default theme for a while because I didn't like, but now that it starts to appear better I would like to try it but unfortunately I can't.

For starters, my option to choose the accent color straight up doesn't show and I haven't seen anyone with the same problem online.

[image]

Secondly if I choose Light or Dark on the settings, the theme goes to a white anyway and the theme doesn't appear to be the Ubuntu default theme and my icons reset as well to a styling that I don't know (super old style). To get an acceptable theme I'm using tweaks and running this options

[image]

I think that my laptop doesn't have the files required to get the default theme.

Comment: Check to see if the default theme files are missing as you suspect in ```/usr/share/themes/```

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen what is the name of the files/folders I should find?

Comment: In there we the Default folder

Comment: The default theme is "Yaru", and in addition there are a range of color variants (which are used when you switch the accent color. So you should have 25 or so `Yaru-...` directories under `/usr/share/themes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue by running the following commands, looks like I didn't have the default theme in my computer.

`sudo apt-get -y install yaru-theme-icon`
`sudo apt-get -y install yaru-theme-gtk`

Yaru was present but only in the shell option, to get the "leggacy applications" and "icons" I had to run the commands above.